# Find old instagram pictures with a certain hashtag

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

The Instagram official API ([link](https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/tags/)) allow us to search for the recent pictures with a certain hashtag by doing a get request to the endpoint `https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/{tag-name}/media/recent?access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN`. By doing so we get the most recent 33 pictures of that hashtag and we also get a `max_tag_id` that allows us to ask for the next 33 pictures.

I want to get pictures that are at least one month old. I could keep on making requests and finding the new `max_tag_id` until I find the pictures that are old enough. The problem is that there are millions of recent pictures and I would take forever to reach the page of the old pictures. The only solution I see is to understand how the `max_tag_id` works and change it manually to find the page of the old pictures.

Here you have 5 different `max_tag_id` of sequential pages:

```
max_tag_ids = [u'AQDYK_538AzbSXpT2wfZrdhtqwJ8Buu0y5_Bcx-dZeQYX-RZeyRE1xW99JUoW4c2SNJ6GZ2Co-6UgWUpzdOCRl3RBIoNZw6ALRZTOYbM0kphPtEahSbv1nOyTO0SpdV3utw', u'AQA7JX63t9iVB8n0PE0_7JqUfYBWwSaukmkHJ6woOh7RTGyjbsRTFzoTr-Lml4rLnMdKKRlqbplTEK6JLfOq7r88fPmepra1SYiZKZNxh7--jxAvqWq5ru-Wt444-LuZQxk', u'AQD8GJCCxWDUd-Gv2Iys1G2RjUozXbAVcZOWa8H29vgq9UMVjD_kPVwp6y-Og2xQXO11R1ck5V925irELWK0MwHvrgGgbVljeGU9j0jpSEEDZ8ZfLmjTkbshiMsGqvw846g', u'AQCbV44lzEIHW4xgz82F-duu1iMIPLvp-ArXoTZrt_DgLwOBVpmWLsNlnyOGKlfimGrhZz3m5aFF-0lRrxNAr82pd9LOpJB06G4wwhv-VGmzZo8ZuBqnEV2LEqjNQudmZlQ', u'AQDX7sXWrADCvno3KUhvsO7r9ldcnGga5R42PSBUre2cVfu660gd232qpj74TQoboQFSS-y2jKwE2N4NAr4tsylqeA1BwArlcQpnsGO9SqusCpUG38KKJzjx7wXhdQIYE0A']
```

All the ids have the same length of 131 characters. The previous pages `max_tag_id` are always bigger than the new pages `max_tag_id`.

```
for i in xrange(len(max_tag_ids)-1):
    assert max_tag_ids[0]>max_tag_ids[1], 'you should never read this'
```

So I tried to use very small `max_tag_id` (e.g. `'0'*131`) but I get the following reply:
'max_id is not a valid cursor.'

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

A bit of history on hashtag and date/time search:

Instagram for some reason is trying to prevent 3rd-party developers to do hashtag search by time. At first `max_tag_id` and `min_tag_id` values used to be epoch time stamps, so it was easy to do date/time search for hashtags. Next, they changed `max_tag_id` and `min_tag_id` to `media_id`, so it became a 2 step approach to find a media_id with the time stamp you want to search and you could apply it to `max_tag_id`, but now they have changed to some hashed value that is hard to decode. So my guess is that Instagram is trying to prevent 3rd-party developers from do this.

I have implemented date/time search in https://www.picodash.com for all queries except hashtags. I have tried to decode the tag_id, but never was successful, and have not gotten no response from Instagram as to why they made this difficult.